# How to break or stop ruby_block running in loop cause of "subscribes"

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Hi have a recipe where I am trying to check if a service is running and accessible.

So I have a "**ruby_block**" which checks if service is running if not it "**notifies**" to "**execute**" block to start it, once execute block starts the service I need to again check if it running by calling "ruby_block" using "**subscribes**"
But when service fails to start "**ruby_block**" goes in unstoppable  loop.

## Below is recipe which describes the workflow

```
ruby_block 'check_if_Service_running' do

  block do
    # ...some logic to check service

    # generates a return code 301 if successful or any other value if fails and 
    # assign it to an attribute check eg. value = return_code   
  end

  notifies :run, 'execute['start_service']', :immediately
  subscribes :run,'execute[Start_Service]', :immediately
end

execute 'Start_Service' do
  #...code to start the service

  
  action :nothing

  not_if { value == 301 }
end
```

---

So in this case when Services fails to start even after execute block, ruby_block keeps on running and notify "execute" block and so on

## note: when service starts successfully it does show expected behavior

But some times when service does not start it goes in loop

Please help me here to stop "ruby_block" being going in loop cause of subscribes for more than 2 times and stop everything (loop) if service felt to start

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a custom resource instead, you want more explicit control over things than the DSL will give you.

Comment: Thanks!, Yeah that would work for me, but I am expecting to achieve this with less complexity .
Please suggest if there is anything which could be done here to stop the loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you have a `ruby_block` resource that is both subscribing to and notifying the same `execute` resource, which is probably always the wrong thing to do.

Why are you using `ruby_block` and `execute` resources instead of just a `service` resource?

Your recipe looks more like you are thinking of Chef of something you tell to do things in a particular way. Instead, Chef recipes should be a description of a state you want to assert, and then let Chef figure out how to achieve that state. Tell Chef you want your service to be running, and worry about adding more detail if and only if that doesn't work. It is uncommon to need to provide that extra detail.

Comment: Thanks David M 
service I am trying to start is not registered, I have to start it by going to a particular  location and use the shell command, thus opted for execute resource.
and @coderanger, Yeah I have created a custom resource to achieve this

Thanks for your valuable inputs here folks :)
I have cre